# How to prevent absoloutely positioned grandchild from stretching containers scrollHeight/scrollWidth?

Tags: html, css

I would like a container to have scroll size that respects it's child only.

Unfourtunately, the child (`.scrollable` in the example below) contains absoulutely positioned elements that may stretch beyond the bounds of child. I would like the containers scroll size to ignore these overflows.

How could I do that?

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scrollable {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(#f79862, #fd6a02)
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(#f79862, #fd6a02)
}

.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #09c;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="overflow">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the context of this example - I want the scrolling to end as soon as the last orange line is visible instead of showing all of the blue bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `overflow:hidden` to the `.scrollable` div so that it won't exceed its parent div

Try this

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scrollable {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(#f79862, #fd6a02);
  overflow: hidden; /*added here*/
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(#f79862, #fd6a02)
}

.overflow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #09c;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="overflow">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, seems so obvious now. Thanks!